# Complexity of Overlaps SortedSet<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, sortedset

in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.overlaps?view=net-6.0), the complexity is indicated as O(n)

but if you look at the implementation

```
  foreach (T item in other)
            {
                if (Contains(item))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

, then the search method is called for each element, which gives the complexity O(m*log(n))

who is really right?

Comment: `Contains` is O(1) operation for HashMaps, and iterating each item of an array is O(n). Combining both makes O(n)

Comment: @CihanYakar could you please clarify where `HashMap` come from in your comment? I don't see any indication of [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.contains?view=net-6.0) to be O(1) for SortedSet (at least not in the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L693) nor in the docs which says O(log(n))...

Comment: I think it's a mistake in the docs.

Comment: @CihanYakar, not, it is not `O(1)`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Somehow I assumed it is HashSet<T> which has O(1) contains. But you are totally right bcs SortedSet’s contains has different complexity. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is mistake in the docs, if you check docs for [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.contains?view=net-6.0) (and it's implementation using [`FindNode`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/add51b82baf268c3678bdd124480a46b89d72ce4/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L693)) you will see:

> This method is an `O(log n)` operation.

Which makes `Overlaps` to be `O(n log m)` where `m` - number of elements in the "this" collection and `n` is the number of elements in `other`.

Created [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8965) for the docs.

**UPD**

PR was merged and now docs say:

> This method is an `O(n log m)` operation, where `m` is `Count` and `n` is the number of elements in `other`.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The documentation is wrong.

Similar methods like [`IsSubsetOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.issubsetof?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-sortedset-1-issubsetof(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) leverage the `O(1)` [`GetViewBetween`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.getviewbetween?view=net-6.0) method to achieve `O(n)` complexity when comparing two SortedSets with the same equality comparer.

[`Overlaps`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L1330) also has logic to optimize this case too, making it an `O(1)` operation if the two sets' min and max values prove that they can't overlap at all. In theory, `Overlaps` could apply an additional optimization to be `O(n)` when compared to another sorted set with overlapping ranges, but it doesn't.

In all other cases, as you've pointed out, Overlap resorts to a loop with a `Contains` check, and [`Contains` is an `O(log n)` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.contains?view=net-6.0#remarks), making the loop (on average, assuming many non-matching values) `O(n * log m)` where `n` is the number in the other collection and `m` is the number in this collection.